# Green’s Function for Regular Sturm-Liouville Problems

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, sturm-liouville

$''$ We are interested in solving problems like:

$Ly := (py')'− qy = f$

with boundary conditions

$β_1y(a) + γ_1 y'(a)=0$ , 
$β_2y(b) + γ_2 y'(b)=0.$

To this end we define the operator
$Ly = (py')'− qy$
under the assumption that $λ = 0 $ is not an eigenvalue of $L$ and where $p, p'$
, and $q$ are continuous on $[a, b]$,
$p(x) > 0$ on $[a, b]$ and

$|γj| + |βj|\neq0$ for j = 1, 2, in the Hilbert space H = $L^2$(a, b)

One can prove that the solution of this problem is unique and is given by the following type:

$ y(x)=\int_{b}^a g(x,z)f(z) dz $

where $g(x,z)$ is Green's function for operator $L$. $''$

My question is why the assumption that $λ$ IS NOT an eigenvalue of $L$ is necessary for the theory . What could have happen if $ 0 $ was an eigenvalue? Although it seems simple , I've been stuck to this point... I would appreciate any help.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The operator $L$ defined on a domain $\mathcal{D}(L)$ of twice continuously differentiable functions satisfying the two endpoint conditions is symmetric in the inner product $L^2[a,b]$ where $(h,k)=\int_{a}^{b}h(t)\overline{k(t)}dt$, which is to say that
$$
             (Lf,g) = (f,Lg),\;\;\; f,g\in\mathcal{D}(L).
$$
Because of this, if $Lu = 0$ for $u\in\mathcal{D}(L)$, then
$$
        (Lf,u) = (f,Lu) = 0,\;\;\; f\in\mathcal{D}(L).
$$
That keeps the range from being full, which means you cannot solve $Lf=g$ for all $g$--it is necessary that $(g,u)=0$. Furthermore, even if you can solve $Lf=g$, then $f$ is not unique because $L(f+\alpha u)=0$ for all scalars $\alpha$. On the other hand, if $\lambda=0$ is not an eigenvalue, then $L$ is invertible as stated using a Green function.

Comment: Well...I 'd thought that it would cause trouble with the uniqueness of $f$ but I hadn't thought about the fact that you can solve the $Lf=g$ for certain $g$ in this case! You explained me this in detail, thanks a lot for your time!!

Comment: @kaithkolesidou : You're welcome.

Comment: @kaithkolesidou : Select to check mark to the left of my answer to accept the answer. You can even +1 it if you like it.